# What user permissions are required for the development of webparts in Sharepoint Framework?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx, spfx-webparts, pnp

As I am new to SharePoint Framework, I want to know what all user permissions are required for the development of web-parts in SharePoint Framework, along with web-part deployment in Microsoft Teams as well.

Comment: Hi Nidhi, are you still alive?

Answer (score 2):

For development and local workbench testing no permissions required.

To deploy SPFx package to App catalog, you should have **site collection administrator** permissions on App catalog.

Comment: Hi @Emiel, Does this answers your question? If Yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you and it will remove this question from unanswered questions list.

Comment: Can contributor permission of App catalog site able to upload Apps?

Answer (score 2):

As Genesh says, for development and local workbench testing no permissions required.

The account used for granting the requested permissions will need to be a **tenant administrator**. The SharePoint administrator permission isn't sufficient as the operation is actually performed on the tenant's associated **Azure Active Directory tenant**.